# Initializing instance method values for inherited models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i need help on single table inheritance (STI) and initializing default values for inherited models.

for example, i have Omnivore, Herbivore, and Herbivore models which inherit from Player, and Player inherits from User.

via STI, all models have lvl, xp, hp, ap and max_xp, max_hp, and max_ap.

via the database, all values default to 0 or 1. (:users, :xp, :integer, default: 0)

but what i'm trying to do is to initialize different values for instances of each class. For example each new Carnivore object would have set values of LVL: 1 XP: 0/50, HP: 5/5, AP: 3/3, while Herbivore would have LVL:1 XP: 0/50, HP: 3/3, AP: 5/5, Herbivore LVL: 1 XP: 0/50, AP/HP: 4/4.

also, when xp value exceeds max_xp, lvl would be incremented. something like

```
when xp > max_hp 
 lvl += 1
end
```

or

```
xp = 70

lvl = case xp
  when 0..40 then 1
  when 41..60 then 2
  when 61..70 then 3
  when 71..100 then 4
  else "Overpowered"
end

where do I put this?
```

how might u approach both issues?

i thought something like this might work for initializing values

```
def initialize
  @xp = 100
end
```

but that didn't work, instead setting @xp to nil. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the values in a before_save callback on the model.